# RewriteCond if x character in REQUEST_URI

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite, apache2

This is probably a simple answer but I am having a hard time figuring this out.

Let's say I have the following url `http://www.somewhere.com/ENGESV/somepath/index.html`

I am trying match `RewriteCond` if the beginning of URL path has uppercase or lowercase, 0-9 and 6 characters e.g. `/ENGESV/` would meet my condition.

I have tried a few alternations of the below with no luck

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.somewhere.com)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/([0-9a-zA-Z]{6})\/(.*)$
RewriteRule .* http://www.somewhereelse.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex seems okay, although you don't need the capturing groups. See:
 [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/63o43c/1).

Have you enabled the rewrite module?

`sudo a2enmod rewrite`